# Can't add a property to an array of objects in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Alright guys, I am totally stumped here. A little overview of what I am doing here, I am pulling documents from MongoDB using Mongoose. Here's an example of the array of objects returned from the mongoose query:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5fdd2f26724b95367bb08557",
    "buyer": "5f976504231cd73151dcdc28",
    "project": "5fa30ee658eba14ca75eb69c",
    "createdBy": "5fdbd0f42d8fb4348f3136fd",
    "createdAt": "2020-12-18T22:37:26.170Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-12-18T22:37:26.170Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5fdd3216724b95367bb0856f",
    "buyer": "5f976504231cd73151dcdc28",
    "project": "5fa30ee658eba14ca75eb69c",
    "createdBy": "5fdbd0f42d8fb4348f3136fd",
    "createdAt": "2020-12-18T22:49:58.320Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-12-18T22:49:58.320Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Once pulled, I am randomizing them with a Fisher-Yates style function:

```
async function randomizer(array){
    let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
      
    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
  
      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
  
      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
  
    return array;
}
```

I then take that randomized array and loop through it with a for loop:

```
for(let i = 0; i < reservations.length; i++){
      reservations[i].randomizedOrder = i; // Store randomized order in array
}
```

But the objects in the array are still coming out like this with no added randomizedOrder field:

```
  {
    "_id": "5fdd3216724b95367bb0856f",
    "buyer": "5f976504231cd73151dcdc28",
    "project": "5fa30ee658eba14ca75eb69c",
    "createdBy": "5fdbd0f42d8fb4348f3136fd",
    "createdAt": "2020-12-18T22:49:58.320Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-12-18T22:49:58.320Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
```

Here it is in order:

```
      const options = {
        query: { project: "5fa30ee658eba14ca75eb69c" },
        populate: [],
        pagination: { limit: 0, skip: 0 },
        sort: {},
      };
      
      const reservations = await this.dbService.read('Reservation', options);
      const arr = reservations.data;

      function randomizer(array) {
        let currentIndex = array.length,
            temporaryValue, randomIndex;
    
        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    
            // Pick a remaining element...
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;
    
            // And swap it with the current element.
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }
    
        return array;
      }

      const shuffledReservations = randomizer(arr);

      for(let i = 0; i < shuffledReservations.length; i++){
        arr[i].shuffledReservations = i; // Store randomized order in array
      }
```

I added a console.log() line in the for loop and the for loop is definitely running as it's spitting out console.logs but it's just not adding the randomizedOrder property to reservation. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why are you using async function?

Comment: and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didnt need *await* keyword for calling randomizer! and strip out *async* keyword from function declaration as well.

if you didn't expect this output and you have any problems implementing leave a comment!

```js
let arr = [{
        "_id": "5fdd2f26724b95367bb08557",
        "buyer": "5f976504231cd73151dcdc28",
        "project": "5fa30ee658eba14ca75eb69c",
        "createdBy": "5fdbd0f42d8fb4348f3136fd",
        "createdAt": "2020-12-18T22:37:26.170Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-12-18T22:37:26.170Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5fdd3216724b95367bb0856f",
        "buyer": "5f976504231cd73151dcdc28",
        "project": "5fa30ee658eba14ca75eb69c",
        "createdBy": "5fdbd0f42d8fb4348f3136fd",
        "createdAt": "2020-12-18T22:49:58.320Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-12-18T22:49:58.320Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
];
function randomizer(array) {
    let currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    console.log(array)
    return array;
}

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i].randomizedOrder = i; // Store randomized order in array
}

const shuffledReservations = randomizer(arr);
```